# Publish page remotely

Tags: remote, wp-remote-post

Is it possible to publish a page to WordPress remotely?

Example diagram:
[image]

Comment: Yes. You can do so using the REST API; [see the documentation for details](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#create-a-page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pat is correct the REST API is the best way to add a new post/page to your site. Here is a more complete guide with an example: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/rest-api-create-delete-posts.html#create_post

Example code for publishing a new post:

```
$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://WEBSITE/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'LOGIN:PASSWORD' )
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'title'   => 'My test',
        'status'  => 'draft', // ok, we do not want to publish it immediately
        'content' => 'lalala',
        'categories' => 5, // category ID
        'tags' => '1,4,23' // string, comma separated
        'date' => '2015-05-05T10:00:00', // YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
        'excerpt' => 'Read this awesome post',
        'password' => '12$45',
        'slug' => 'new-test-post' // part of the URL usually
        // more body params are here:
        // developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post
    )
) );

$body = json_decode( $api_response['body'] );

// If the post was published successfully we can display a little message
if( wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $api_response ) === 'Created' ) {
    echo 'The post ' . $body->title->rendered . ' has been created successfully';
}
```

As you can see you simply pass on the data for for post via the body argument.

**Authorization:**

*Login:PASSWORD* on line 3 is the pair of username and password of a website user that has post publishing capabilities. A better method for Authorization may be to use the Application Passwords plugin and setup tokens. You can find the plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/

Comment: Please [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/361004/edit) to include the relevant code from the linked page, in case the link becomes unavailable for some reason. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), specifically the section titled **Provide context for links**.